# sign up for an event/organization

Tags: word-usage

What are the things that you can sign up for?

Is it correct to say "*to sign up for an event*", the event being an online live chat session?

The definition of *sign up* in the [COBUILD Advanced English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sign-up) says that *if you sign up for an organization or if an organization signs you up, you sign a contract officially agreeing to do a job or course of study.*

Do you sign up only for organizations?

I saw the verb used in sentences such as "*She's signed up for evening classes at the community college,*" but I'm still not sure what are the things you can sign up for?

Comment: You can sign up for any activity that literally requires that you register to participate. But you can also sign up figuratively for obligations. Thus you can tell your boyfriend, "Look, when I agreed to go out with you, I didn't **sign up** to spend every holiday with your parents."

Comment: Did you read the sample sentences at your link? Can you say if the following example sentence used there is relevant to your question: *And I'll bet she wants me to sign up for a whole course of treatment to defuse me.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a would-be participant, you sign up for things where in order to participate, you are required, encouraged or requested to sign up.

Why are people asked to sign up for things?  So that the organizers know how many people are planning to participate.  So they can organize things well, based on the known number of participants.